# Issue with headers on scala from a csv file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to upload a csv file using Scala and Apache Spark but, once I specify the schema with a Spark Structype I have this issue trying to indicate the headers of the csv file-

```
scala> import org.apache.spark

import org.apache.spark


scala> import org.apache.spark.sql

import org.apache.spark.sql


scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext


scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types

import org.apache.spark.sql.types


scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions


scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans

import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans


scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.ClusteringEvaluator

import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.ClusteringEvaluator


scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler


scala> val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details

sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@f24a84


scala> import sqlContext.implicits

import sqlContext.implicits


scala> import sqlContext

| val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("ID_CALLE",IntegerType,true),StructField("TIPO", IntegerType, true),StructField("CALLE",IntegerType,true),StructField("NUMERO",IntegerType,true), StructField("LONGITUD",DoubleType,true),StructField("LATITUD",DoubleType,true),StructField("TITULO",IntegerType,true)))

<console>:2: error: '.' expected but ';' found.

val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("ID_CALLE",IntegerType,true),StructField("TIPO", IntegerType, true),StructField("CALLE",IntegerType,true),StructField("NUMERO",IntegerType,true), StructField("LONGITUD",DoubleType,true),StructField("LATITUD",DoubleType,true),StructField("TITULO",IntegerType,true)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is small typo error in your code. If you see your code carefully you will find below mistake

```
scala> import sqlContext

| val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("ID_CALLE",IntegerType,true),StructField("TIPO", IntegerType, true),StructField("CALLE",IntegerType,true),StructField("NUMERO",IntegerType,true), StructField("LONGITUD",DoubleType,true),StructField("LATITUD",DoubleType,true),StructField("TITULO",IntegerType,true)))
```

Everywhere you are typing new line of code only after `scala>` but in above code you are typing after `|`

So just type you code like below

```
scala> import sqlContext._
scala> val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("ID_CALLE",IntegerType,true),StructField("TIPO", IntegerType, true),StructField("CALLE",IntegerType,true),StructField("NUMERO",IntegerType,true), StructField("LONGITUD",DoubleType,true),StructField("LATITUD",DoubleType,true),StructField("TITULO",IntegerType,true)))
```